# Расшарить программно принтеры

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

Добрый день!

Пытаюсь расшарить программно принтеры с использованием С#.
Пробовал передавать скрипт prncnfg.vbs с аргументами . Пример скрипта с аргументами:

```
prncnfg.vbs -t -p "Sony DPP-FP60" -h "Share" +shared -direct
```

и использовал `SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer`, но не могу включить общий доступ более, чем на 1 принтер. Кроме того, после включения шары на 1 принтер уже не сработает шара на другой. Задержки в выполнении потоков не приносят результатов. Вручную через командную строку всё работает корректно.

Проект заключается в следующем: получаем список принтеров

```
foreach (var printer in PrintersList.SelectedItems)
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PrintersList.SelectedValue))
     {
        printersList.Add((string)printer);
     }
}
```

Потом передаём его в метод. Принтеры обрабатываются отдельно в списке, но включение доступа не передается на 2 и более принтера. Имя для доступа получается задать для всех выбранных принтеров.

```
foreach (string printers in list)
{
  string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Name = '{0}'", printers);
  ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
  ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
  ManagementObject printer = collection.Cast<ManagementObject>().ElementAt(0);

  printer.Properties["ShareName"].Value = shareName;
  printer.Put();
```

Если включить значение,

```
printer.Properties["Shared"].Value = true;
```

то включается 1 принтер для расшаривания, а потом валится ошибка. Значение Shared, как я понимаю из примеров WMI, не позволяет это сделать массово.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно это решить как-то или порекомендуйте библиотеку, которая умеет это делать

Answer (score 1):

Раз хоть один принтер раздавался, спрашивать, с какими правами выполнялся скрипт, пожалуй, не стоит :). Единственно, я бы поменял строку запроса на такую (так обычно быстрее):

```
"Select * from Win32_Printer Where Network = FALSE"
```

А скрипт у вас не работает потому, что вы не меняете ShareName для каждого следующего принтера, что запрещено в системе. Другой явной ошибки я тут не вижу (может, не туда гляжу :)).

По крайней мере, если было необходимо стартовать принт-сервер с нуля и не мучаться с шарингом, я использовал вот такой скрипт:

```
Comp = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & Comp & "\root\cimv2")
Set LocalPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Printer Where Network = FALSE")
i = 1
For Each objPrinter in LocalPrinters
    objPrinter.Shared = TRUE
    objPrinter.ShareName = "Printer" & i
    objPrinter.Put_
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Да, "Остап не баловал разнообразием комбинаций", и принтеры у меня имели скромные имена с перечислением, но все в сети знали, что 1 - это лазерный для чистовой печати, 2 - для черновой, а 3 - цветной струйный.

Comment: А можно при этом Sharename задавать по-русски?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Не пробовал, но проблем не вижу